# will or going to in this case

Tags: future-tense

I feel tired I **am going to** bed or I **will go** to bed

I think the second one is better but that decision of" going to bed "has been taken before because feeling tired is not something that comes all of a sudden, when you say this you have already made up your mind. It is not a right now decision.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct.  I think it's more common to say

> "I feel tired, I'm going to bed."

than

> "I feel tired. I will go to bed."

The second choice sounds like a robot, and doesn't sound natural.

Sure, when you say "I'm going to bed now", it is in the present tense. It can be a sort of extended present tense though, like you are on your way to bed now, the whole process will take a few minutes, etc.

However, considering other use cases... it might depend on whether you are announcing it to a room full of people, or just thinking to yourself: "I feel tired. I will go to bed in 10 minutes."